# Can't publish my Python packe to PyPi - Bad Gateway

Tags: python, pypi, bad-gateway

I am currently trying to publish a Python package on PyPi. I have built the package and the command
`twine check dist/*`
has also run successfully.
Now when I try to upload it via Twine, I get a 502 Bad Gateway Error:

```
Received "502: Bad Gateway" Package upload appears to have failed.  Retry 5 of 5
Content received from server:
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.13.9</center>
</body>
</html>

HTTPError: 502 Bad Gateway from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Bad Gateway
```

Any ideas?

Comment: wait, try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyPI had a brief outage, should be back now: https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/9151